# Automatically Enable/Disable a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a button(for asking questions) and countdown timer(where time="2017/04/30 10:30:00), now what I want is when time=reaches 0 automatically disable a button and when time is >0 automatically enable the button again.

I have only one  variable for saving date var time="2017/04/30". I guess constantly checking for time will be best option to make button enable/disable, but i do not know how to do it.

Comment: Add your relevant code please.

Comment: And include a more spefific problem statement as it relates to that code

Comment: your countdown timer plugin must be having few callback function like the one which gets called when timer reaches to end OR timer tick callback. you can make use of them to decide the button state.

Comment: https://github.com/sectalks/sectalks.github.io/blob/master/countdown.html, right now I am using this code from github

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post.

Comment: learn about setTimeout function of JS, it gets call after regular intervals.. you can use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to do this in one's front-end script as almost anyone with a basic JavaScript knowledge can re-enable the button when `time==0` which I assume you don't want to happen.

I'll suggest doing this in one's server-side code. In brief:

1. check timer when generating the page, if timer is out, generate the disabled button without any code that was supposed to handle the click event.
2. check timer when handling the request triggered by the button click, return 404 or other error message if timer is out.

---

All that being said, if you "have to" do this quick dirty way, you can simply use a `setInterval` or `setTimeout`:

```
//javascript
// check timer every 200 ms
var TICK = 200; 
var checkTimerTask = setInterval(function(){
    if (getTimer() == 0){
        document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = true; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = false;
    }
    // to stop checking uncomment the following line.
    // clearInterval(checkTimerTask);
}, TICK);
```

Comment: Thank you very much , grt help!

Comment: small question, why are you calling document at the end of the file, what does the doc does? sorry i am a beginner in js

Comment: +ben To capture the current `document` reference as a local parameter to avoid using the 'global' `document` variable. I'm removing it as it is causing confusions but not directly related to the question.